# how to print out match unique pattern from 2 different file using perl

Tags: perl

I'am try to print out matched pattern from 2 file that have almost same data but have slightly different. 
[below is the example file][1]

```
File 1
Orig : 109 ABCDEFG1
Orig : 119 ORANGECOLOUR


File 2 
Clone : 108 abcd_efg_1
Clone : 113 orange_colour


Ouput expected
Orig : 109 ABCDEFG1
Clone : 108 abcd_efg_1

Orig : 119 ORANGECOLOUR
Clone : 113 orange_colour
```

So, based on the example above the different from 2 file is only the upper case/lower case and got some extra character "_". So how to print out matched data into 3rd file using perl

```html
open FILE1,'<FILE1' or die $!;
open FILE2,'<FILE2' or die $!;
open FILE3, '>Output' or die $!;

my @array3 = <FILE1>;
my @array4 = <FILE2;


foreach $x (@array3) {  if($x =~ /(\S+) (\d+) (\S+)/) { $temp_data = $3; 
       foreach $y (@array4) { if($y =~ /\b$temp_data\b/i) {print FILE3 "$x$y\n";}} 
}}

close FILE1;
close FILE2;
close FILE3;
```

Above is the script that i have done. When I used this script, it only print out the pattern that are totally matched without consider the upper/lower case. .Below is the output when I used that code

```html
Output file

Orig : Bluecolour
Clone : Bluecolour

Orig : Greycolour1
clone : Greycolour1
```

Comment: please show us the code that you've written that you're having a problem with. This is not a code-writing service; you have to show some effort and ask a specific question on the part of the code you're having issues with.

Comment: Do the two files have the same number of rows? Does line N from file 1 always correspond to line N of file 2?

Comment: No, the line not always corresponding to each other

Comment: I already add the code that i have done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If provided files and conditions are complete, following will work

```
open F1, 'f1.txt';
open F2, 'f2.txt';

my @f2 = <F2>;
foreach my $string1 (<F1>) {
    chomp($string1);
    my ($pattern1) = $string1 =~ m/(\S+)$/;
    foreach my $string2 (@f2) {
        chomp($string2);
        ($_) = $string2 =~ m/(\S+)$/;
        s/[^a-z0-9]//ig;
        print $string1 . "\n" . $string2 . "\n" if ($pattern1 =~ /^$_$/i);
    }
}
```

outputs:

```
Orig : ABCDEFG1
Clone : abcd_efg_1
Orig : ORANGECOLOUR
Clone : orange_colour
```

**upd:**
you've added numbers to the input files, the script still works, no modification needed

outpus:

```
Orig : 109 ABCDEFG1
Clone : 108 abcd_efg_1
Orig : 119 ORANGECOLOUR
Clone : 113 orange_colour
```

Comment: if my files also consist of number?i already add to my question above

Comment: when i use your code, it only print out 2 line only

Comment: Still works even with numbers in a files, no script edit needed.

Comment: yes it work, got some problem with my file only..thanks